# 'touchend' fired on scroll the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, iscroll, touch-event

A sample mobile app created with the help of HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery. In the app listed number of users details with right arrow mark. arrow mark has `touchend` event. which touchend handler navigate to next screen.

On touch the arrow mark and scroll the list above (screen is scrolling) and release the finger the `touchend` has fired.

arrow mark touchend will fire only click the element but its called on scroll the screen. any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: why don't you use "click" instead? touchstart/end use would always make the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Ya! I applied "click" instead of "touchend" its working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue by applying "click" event instead of "touchend" event.